# shadow only looks good when it has to be behind the character. on the front does not work correctly

Tags: image, lighting, shadows, shadowcatcher, light-groups

how to make the shadow stay correctly in front of the image plane, when it is supposed to be behind it is perfect, when it needs to be in front it is cut off and away from the character.[In this first image we see the error that happens, whenever the shadow needs to be in front and in no way is it correctly close to the character's feet.In the second image we see that if you throw the shadow back it fits perfectly to the character.
[image: ][1]1]

[image]

Comment: Looking OK when the shadow is behind the man could be an optical illusion. Maybe he is still hovering above the plane and when you move the light source this becomes obvious.

Comment: Is there any way to agree on this? Or do I need to create an illusion with animation in the light?

Comment: The best way is to have a cut out figure with both feet perfectly horizontal. You can edit the photo and make both legs equal in size, or cut the back leg and import it as a separate plane and scale it, or just take a new photo with the feet placement in mind.